# Why is AdSense showing "wepage not available" in ad slots on my phone?

Tags: google-adsense, bugs, advertising

I tested the mobile version of my site both on my computer and on my older android phone with a pull-out keyboard.

On my computer, the advertisement loads fine, but on my phone, the advertisement tries to load but I receive the browser "webpage not available" message inside the advertisement space.

I tested another website that also uses ads on my computer and on the phone, and the results are the same.

So I'm curious. Does adsense have bugs or is google trying to tell us they're ready to pull the plug on their advertising?

The other site I tested is clickindia.com.